# remort object(flex) and ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a custom java class which has an ArrayList and corresponding  to it have a custom vo class which has ArrayCollection (in Flex).

I want to return data from Java to flex. Every variable in java is getting mapped to vo perfectly except for ArrayList.

When trying to retrive

When trying to retrive `exposureUSDList` (which is an arrayList) in flex I am getting empty ArrayCollection. It is not getting mapped properly

Please find my code below:

Flex Code:

```
package com.example.vo
{

import com.adobe.cairngorm.vo.IValueObject;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;


    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="com.example.vo.Summary")]

    public class Summary
    {
            public var productId : String;
            public var clientId : String;
            public var brokerId : String;
            public var acctNo : Number;
            public var exposureUSDList:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();




    }
}
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.vo;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Summary implements Serializable {


    static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private String productId ;
    private String clientId ;
    private String brokerId ;
    private String acctNo ;
    private ArrayList exposureUSDList= new ArrayList();

    public String getProductId() {
            return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(String productId) {
            this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
            return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    public String getBrokerId() {
            return brokerId;
    }
    public void setBrokerId(String brokerId) {
            this.brokerId = brokerId;
    }
    public int getAcctNo() {
            return acctNo;
    }
    public void setAcctNo(int acctNo) {
            this.acctNo = acctNo;

    public ArrayList getExposureUSDList() {
            return exposureUSDList;
    }

    public void setExposureUSDList(double exposureUSD) {
            this.exposureUSDList.add(exposureUSD);
            }


}
```

Please Help!!

Comment: I think the reason could be that you're passing double to the array list setter

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason could be that you're passing double to the array list setter. Try pass ArrayList.